# Two-tailed test: Biased coin

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, distribution-tails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjYk0.jpg)

Can anyone guide me through this question?

From what I gather, I have to do a hypothesis test and get a number of consecutive tails such that I can reject H0.
H0: The coin is unbiased
H1: The coin is biased

I’m unfamiliar with what I should do. Should I use a geometric distribution for this case?
X ~ Geo (0.5),
X = number of consecutive heads up to and including first tail

Can I approximate this to a normal distribution?
E(X) = 1/p and Var(X) = (1-p)/p^2
X = N(2,2)

And then do P(X>n-2) < 0.025 in order for H0 to be rejected? Where n is the number of throws until first tailed is obtained?

I’m not sure why I thought of approximating to a normal distribution, but we are not allowed to use calculators/ not given any formula table etc in the test where this question came from, so I assume it has to be simple.

Comment: I think that the image description assumes consecutive *heads* rather than consecutive *tails*.  The place to start is the definitions.  What is the source of the problem - is it from a book or class?  Assuming so, what is the exact definition/meaning/intent that your book or class taught you of the phrase : "Use a $2$-tailed test at the $5\%$ significance  level"?

Comment: Consecutive heads from the start with no tails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothesis test we're performing is $$H_0:p=1/2$$ $$H_a:p\neq 1/2$$ where $p$ is the (true) probability of landing on heads.

Suppose you flip the coin $X$ times until observing your first tails. Then $N=X-1$ and the pmf of $X$ becomes $$p_{X}(x)=(0.5)^x:x=1,2,3,...$$ The cdf of $X$ is $$P_{X}(x)=1-(.5)^x$$

In finding our rejection region for a two$-$tailed test we typically solve the equations $P_X(x)=0.025$ and $P_X(x)=0.975$ to identify the ${2.5}^{\text{th}}$ and ${97.5}^{\text{th}}$ percentiles of $X$ given $H_0$. But these respective solutions are $\approx 0.04,5.32$ neither of which belong in the support of $X$. The smallest possible outcome of $X$ larger than our critical value $0.04$ is $1$, but including the outcome of $1$ in our rejection region would lead to a $p-$value that's at least $0.50$. In other words, we need only identify the upper $2.5$% to find the critical region. Since $P(X\geq 6)= 0.03125$ and $P(X\geq 7)\approx 0.016$ we see  flipping the coin at least $7$ times lands us in the upper $2.5$%. This corresponds to observing at least $N=7-1=6$ consecutive heads.